# Sample application for Android Tesing

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to android testing. Can anybody please suggest me where I can get sample application along with test projects?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html) should lead you in the right direction. It includes how to build a sample application and additional resources.

Comment: You should avoid the answers that contains only a link. A good answer is where you explain the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's framework called
 `Robotium` 
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started
http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium
also

http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/user-guide.html

you might want to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Robotium is overkill for the moment, though you should remember it.

Start by reading the material regarding Testing in the Developers Guide. Its on the Dev Guide tab. One area at the bottom of Framework Topics, the other is under Developing.

There are two tutorials: Hello, Testing and Activity Testing. There's also a sample test project for the Note Pad sample app.

Of course, testing can mean many different things. I can't think of anything offhand that's for beginners. I know Beck's Test-Driven Development, and Working With Legacy Code (forgot the author, but you can Google it) for learning how to effectively unit test in OOP environments.